# How to index both single and range of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to index a both single and range of columns in a pandas dataframe. To be specific, in a dataset of 30 columns, I would like to create a new dataset with only column index-number [0] and [12 to 20].

I tried `new_df = all_df.iloc[:, (0, 12:20)]` OR`new_df = all_df.iloc[:, [0, 12:20]]` OR google any possible solution but keep getting *invalid syntax error*. How can I index the column in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
new_df=all_df.iloc[:, [12, 20]] #only 12th and 20th columns

new_df = all_df.iloc[:, 12:20] #select columns in range 12 through 20

new_df = all_df[[all_df.columns[0]] + all_df.columns[12:20].to_list()] # select specific columns (first and 12:20)
```

also you can use @chrslg's solution:

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, [0]+list(range(12,20))]
```

Comment: Thank you but what about the first column? I want both 0 AND 12:20 columns.

Comment: you can use: `new_df=all_df[[all_df.columns[0]] + all_df.columns[12:20].to_list()]` first get first column then get 12:20 columns finally combine this to list and select.

Comment: Upvoted. An edit suggestion tho, just to conclude explicitly on the consequence of your first to lines: that means that ``df.iloc[:, [0]+list(range(12,20))]`` selects columns 0 + 12 to 20 (excluded for 20, as all other solutions).